# Unable to display VF pie chart

Tags: visualforce-charting

I have a custom object "Position" which has a lookup field on Product and a number type field "Quantity__c" . I have created a page where I have to display a VF Pie chart which has Products with Quanity. However its not displaying the same. Below is the code snippet. Kindly suggest where am I missing.

Page:

```
<td>
<apex:pageblock title="Pie Chart" >
    <apex:chart height="250" width="350" data="{!pieData}"> 
        <apex:pieSeries tips="true" dataField="pdata" labelField="name"/> 
        <apex:legend position="bottom"/>
    </apex:chart>
</apex:pageblock>
</td>
```

Controller:

```
public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() 
{  
    List<PieWedgeData> pdata = new List<PieWedgeData>();
    List<Position__c> post = new List<Position__c>();  

    String sql = 'SELECT Name, Product__c, Quantity__c FROM Position__c';
    post = Database.Query(sql);
    for(Position__c temp: post)
    {           
        pdata.add(new PieWedgeData(temp.Product__c,temp.Quantity__c));
    }
    return pdata;  
}  

// Wrapper class  
public class PieWedgeData {  
    public String name { get; set; }  
    public Decimal pdata { get; set; }  

    public PieWedgeData(String name, Decimal pdata) 
    {  
        this.name = name;  
        this.pdata = pdata;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: When you say 'It is not displaying the same', what do you mean?  What is it that you think it should be displaying and what is it actually displaying?  Perhaps a screenshot of the outcome would be helpful.

Comment: The code looks fine - do you have any data in the Position__c table?

Comment: @ sfdc_ninja Its not displaying anything. Just the pageblock title "Pie Chart".                                                          @Keith C Yes, there is data in Position's table.

Comment: I pasted your page and code into an org, removed your query and added a few hard coded PieWedgeData items and it displayed fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data contains null, the graph won't be displayed.

I used the following code, the chart didn't show up.
I looked at the data in debug log, some are null.

```
public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() 
{  
    List<PieWedgeData> pdata = new List<PieWedgeData>();
    List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();  
    String sql = 'SELECT Name, Industry, AnnualRevenue FROM Account';
    acc = Database.Query(sql);
    for(Account temp: acc)
    {           
        String ind = temp.Industry;
        Decimal ann = temp.AnnualRevenue;
        if (ann == null) ann = 0;
        pdata.add(new PieWedgeData(ind, ann));
    }
    System.debug(pdata);
    return pdata;  
}
```

Data:

```
PieWedgeData:[name=null, pdata=null], PieWedgeData:[name=Biotechnology, pdata=30000000], PieWedgeData:[name=Energy, pdata=null]
```

After I added the following lines before pdata.add(...), the chart showed up.

```
    if (ind == null) ind = 'NA';
    if (ann == null) ann = 0;
```

[image]

Comment: Yes... The problem was with null.... Thanks a bunch.